# In solr search, solve the error: model 'X' has an empty model_attr 'company' and doesn't allow a default or null value

Tags: python, django, solr

I am using solr search in django. When I am rebuilding the index with Solr, I get the following error:

```
model 'X' has an empty model_attr 'company' and doesn't allow a default or null value.
```

Does anyone know mistake I made, and how can I solve this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it as

```
indexes.CharField(model_attr='company', null=True)
```

and if you want to allow the blank then

add `blank=True`

```
indexes.CharField(model_attr='company', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: My field should like below company = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='company__name'). So when i tried to add like as you said, am getting the following error "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'blank'"

Comment: sorry ..didnt get you

Comment: company = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='company__name')...... This is my field

Comment: try indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='company__name', null=True)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have some entries in your database where a mandatory field is left empty. This can be caused by adding a new mandatory field to an existing model so that existing instances of the model are invalidated due to the empty field.

If you want to enforce the field to have a value, you need to give the existing instances a value for the field. If you use the migration tool [south](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) it will give you an interactive prompt to fix the problem. Check out the "Data Migration" section of the [south documentation](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html).

If it is okay for you to leave the field optional, set `blank=True` (allows leaving the field blank) and `null=True` (sets NULL for empty field).